# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PathRemoveFileSpecA@4

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors

I'm programming with vc6.0 with my backup program. I included shlwapi.h, windows.h and I used PathStripPath function and PathRemoveFileSpec function.

When I complied this message came out.

```
BlackDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PathStripPathA@4
BlackDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PathRemoveFileSpecA@4
```

And I remove usage in my code and this message doesn't come. Thank for you quick advance.

Comment: "*I'm programming with vc6.0*" Oh god why? Please upgrade to something that doesn't predate the C++ standard itself...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The MSDN Library has plenty of information about both of [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773756.aspx) [functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748). If you look towards the ends of the articles you'll see that the functions are defined in `shlwapi.lib`; you need to instruct your linker to include this library for your project to build.

Comment: +1 Also, instructions for adding the .lib to your project's linker inputs are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235399(VS.60).aspx).